# Spring configuration files loading not working on WebSphere 7

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, websphere, classpath

I have an application packaged as follow:

```
+EAR
  +WAR
  +ejb.jar
  +lib
     +core.jar
     +plugin1.jar
     +plugin2.jar
     ...
```

Each "pluginX.jar" contains a spring configuration file in the root.
When the application starts, the core.jar tries to load the spring configurations files:

```
String matchString = "classpath*:/./Plugin.*.spring.xml";
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources(matchString);
```

This works well for JBoss EAP 5.1 but not for WebSphere 7.

I tried to load a resource directly:

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
log.info("class loader: " + cl.toString());
URL u = cl.getResource("Plugin.1.spring.xml");
```

and got the same results, although the log for WebSphere tells that the local classpath contains the "pluginX.jar":

> com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@48da48da[app:CG EAR]
>
> Local ClassPath:
> /opt/IBM/WAS7/AppServer/profiles/srv01/installedApp/cell01/CG.EAR.ear/lib/pluginX.jar
> Parent:com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader@4c654c65
> Delegation Mode: PARENT_LAST

any ideas?

Comment: What 'classpath*:/./Plugin.*.spring.xml' is supposed to mean? Why such a complex pattern?

Comment: it's an Ant-style pattern used to find each file xml like "Plugin.1.spring.xml". It works on JBoss

Comment: SOLVED: it seems that spring class **PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver** is not able traversing jar file in WebSphere.
Class javadocs states: "If a jar URL is obtained, the resolver must be able to get a java.net.JarURLConnection from it, or manually parse the jar URL, to be able to walk the contents of the jar, and resolve the wildcard. This will work in most environments, but will fail in others..."

Answer (score 1):

It's a Classloader issue.
I would suggest you try to change class loading policy for you EAR and WAR.

We have a very similar deployment and we configure like this in WAS 6: go to WAS Console, access **Enterprise Application** => **Your App** => **Class loader** and under **General properties** set:

**Class Loader Order**: "Classes loaded with application class loader fist".

**War class loader policy**: "Class loader for each WAR file in application".

Regarding the source code the snippet below is safer and recommended to avoid classloading issues when loading resources:

`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("Plugin.1.spring.xml"))`

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same issue today with WebSphere 8.5, 
it looks like the problem is, that the ClassLoader.getResources() returns URLs with protocol "file" and not "jar" and in certain cases does not return the jar files in shared libraries as separate resource URLs but the shared library location (e.g. the folder containing the JARs) as a single resource URL. This seems to confuse the `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` somewhere down the road.

I solved it by

1. overwriting the `convertClassLoaderURL` method and explicitly instantiate a JAR resource if the URL protocol is "file" and the extension is ".jar", and
2. overwriting the `doFindPathMatchingFileResources` method to search inside JAR files of resources that represent directories.

```java
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext() {

    protected ResourcePatternResolver getResourcePatternResolver() {
        return new ServletContextResourcePatternResolver(this) {

            protected Resource convertClassLoaderURL(URL url) {
                if (url.getProtocol().equals("file") && url.getFile().endsWith(".jar")) {
                    try {
                        return new UrlResource("jar", url + "!/");
                    } catch (final MalformedURLException ex) {
                        //LOG.catching(ex);
                    }
                }
                return new UrlResource(url);
            }

            protected Set<Resource> doFindPathMatchingFileResources(Resource rootDirResource, String subPattern) throws IOException {
                Set<Resource> matches = super.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(rootDirResource, subPattern);
                try {
                    File rootDir = rootDirResource.getFile();
                    if (rootDir.isDirectory()) {
                        Set<Resource> containedJARs = doFindMatchingFileSystemResources(rootDir, "*.jar");
                        for (Resource jar : containedJARs) {
                            Set<Resource> matchingResourcesFoundInJar = doFindPathMatchingJarResources(convertClassLoaderURL(jar.getURL()), subPattern);
                            matches.addAll(matchingResourcesFoundInJar);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (final IOException ex) {
                    // LOG.catching(ex);
                }
                return matches;
            }

        }

    };
```

This change also gets rid of the log message:

```
WARN  org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver:
* Skipping [.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is applicable for WAS 8: I stumbled upon this thread and it might be worth mentioning it nonetheless

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html

There is this setting: "*com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.SkipMetaInfResourcesProcessing*" you may need to remove it from your websphere config (if somebody set that) or set the value to false.